# How to change view of object in table cell? - JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have a column of `LocalDateTime` in my `TableView`:

```
column_AddDate = new TableColumn<MyTableItem, LocalDateTime>(TITLE_ADD_DATE)
```

But result - `2016-02-05T12:26:20.506` - is not so pretty as for me. I want to store and sort table data using rules of `LocalDateTime` class, but show it with custom format. For example:

```
formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter); // "2016-02-05 12:26"
```

First, that I've tryed, is to write custom `class DateTimeForTable extends LocalDateTime` and override `toString()` method, but LocalDateTime is final.

So, I think, solution is in using `setCellValueFactory()` method and similar, but I'm not skilled in this.

Please tell me, how to realize this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the way the data is presented, rather than the data itself, you should use a `cellFactory`. (I assume you already have a `cellValueFactory` installed, else you would not see any data at all. Note the `cellFactory` is in addition to the `cellValueFactory`, it does not replace it.)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
column_AddDate.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<MyTableItem, LocalDateTime>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDateTime item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : formatter.format(item));
    }
});
```